# horizontal absolute values of every line

Tags: perl

I am trying to calculate the absolute values of line 2 - values of line 1
and then the horizontal absolute values of every line in my input file. Here's a part of that input.

```
43  402 51  360  
63  60  69  63  
65  53  89  55   
103 138 135 135  
109  36 123  38
```

To be more precise about what im trying to do I made the following example

```
initial data

0 2 0 0
0 1 1 1

next stage (absolute value after subscription the second line minus the first line)  

2 2 0
1 0 0

final stage (horizontal application of abs values until one column remained) 

0
1
```

The below code was a failed attempt to obtain the final stage of the single column. My problem here is that I don't know how to obtain the final (desired) stage by using subroutine, as I believe that it is a better way to solving my problem. Of course, every idea or better approach is welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @rows = 'table_only_numbers';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $rows)

sub ori { 
for ($num_cols=@{ $rows[$r-1]}; $num_cols=1; $num_cols-- ){
    my @diff_diffs = map { abs($diffs[$_-1] - $diffs[$_]) } 1..$num_cols-1;
        @final=@diff_diffs;
    say join ' ',@final;
return (final) }

my $num_cols = @{ $rows[0] };
for my $r (1..$#rows) {
   die "Bad format!" if @{ $rows[$r] } != $num_cols;
     my @diffs = map { abs($rows[$r-1][$_] - $rows[$r][$_]) } 0..$num_cols-1; 

 while ($num_cols>1) 
{   
$final_output = ori(@{ $rows[0] })
say "final_output";
}
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: What's the input data? Please [edit] your question and add that as well.

Comment: I cant upload the entire file it is huge .... If the code works at the initial data that  I gave as an example it is going to work in every file afterwards.

Comment: You didn't give example data. Show us a few lines only. Right now I can see your desired output, but no input at all.

Comment: I did some corrections in my question and I add some data too. Im sorry if dint explained what I trying to do properly but I have only the basic knowledge in programming and perhaps the terminology that Iam using for describing is not the best.

Comment: Thanks. I've rearranged the question for you and improved the formatting. Please check to see if the output is the way you want it. I'm still not clear if we're seeing expected output or actual output. We will need both. Is the output for the same data you're showing us? Run your program with only this small subset of data for now to work on it. It will also help youto indent your code properly to make it easier to read. You've already got `strict` and `warnings`, which is great.

Comment: I think now it is clear. I'm sorry for messing it up .

Comment: Don't worry about it, we're all here to learn. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figure it by myself without subroutines!!! Im posting it in case someone face the same issue in the future.I know that it is an easiest way to do it but as I am newbie in Perl it is the easiest way for me.

So I used:

```
 for the first abs of the line 2 minus the line 1
    my @data = map { abs($current[$_]-$previous[$_]) } 0..$#current;
                push @final, \@data;
```

To obtain the absolute value of row 2 minus the row 1

And after I used 3 times as I had 3 columns left (in my case) the following coding line and each time I Substituted the @xxx with a new variable. and I have desired output of I column.

```
foreach my $row (@XXX) {
    my @data = map { abs(@{$row}[$_]-@{$row}[$_+1]) } 0..$#{$row}-1;
    say join ' ', @data;
    push @XXX, \@data;}
```